# Question about the term of "closed" subscheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Based on the [following lecture](https://youtu.be/LE_gl5RcDnY?t=250), ***open* subscheme** of $X$ is an open subset $U$ of $X$ endowed with the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{U}=\mathcal{O}_{X}|_{U} $
. Such term, 'open'  is pretty intuitive for me. Also, the same [lecturer](https://youtu.be/LE_gl5RcDnY?t=784) on the clip also introduced the ***closed* subscheme** like this,

> **Def**.  **A closed subscheme** of $X$ is a scheme $Y$ with a morphism $i:Y\to X$ such that $i|_{i^{-1}(U)} : i^{-1}(U)\to U $ is an affine
> subscheme for each affine open $U$ in $X$.

( When considering the defintion of **affine subscheme** of $X$, I recongnized that $i^{-1}(U)$ is a subscheme of $U$. (For convenience, $i^{-1}(U):=\operatorname{Spec}A, U:=\operatorname{Spec} B$), i.e there is i) a morphism $i^{-1}(U) \looparrowright  U $ (as a inclusion map) and ii) $B  \twoheadrightarrow A $ (surjective), for each open $U$ in $X$.)

My main question , unlike the 'open' subscheme, I do not now sympathize why the given scheme $Y$ is called **closed** subscheme. I have not yet found out any property or clue about closedness when going over the definition of closed subscheme.

Comment: That definition as you've written it is not correct: you're missing that $i^{-1}(U)\to U$ should be an affine *closed* subscheme. (For a counterexample to the claim as written, try $\Bbb A^1\setminus \{0\} \subset \Bbb A^1$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption is equivalent to $i^{-1}(U)$ is affine and $i^{-1}(U) \rightarrow U$ corresponds to a surjective morphism. If $\phi : R \rightarrow S$ is surjective, then by the first isomorphism theorem, $S = R/ker(\phi)$. Therefore we can think of it as $R \rightarrow R/I$ for some ideal $I$ of $R$.

Recall from affine schemes that $R \rightarrow R/I$ induces a morphism $Spec(R/I) \rightarrow Spec(R)$ that is a homeomorphism onto its range, and its range is $V(I)$ which is a closed set. Therefore, $Spec(R/I) \rightarrow Spec(R)$ can be thought of the inclusion $V(I) \rightarrow Spec(R)$, although there is a caveat : different ideals might have the same $V$'s, so the closed subset doesn't completely determine the morphism.

The definition of a closed subscheme that you provided above states, intuitively, that for every affine open set $U$ of $X$, $i|_{i^{-1}(U)} : i^{-1}(U) \rightarrow U$ is a morphism between affine schemes of the form $Spec(R/I) \rightarrow Spec(R)$, which we can think of as the inclusion from the closed set $V(I)$ to $R$.

Comment: On the second paragraph, can you explain why the range of $\operatorname{Spec}(R/I) \to \operatorname{Spec} R$ becomes $V(I)$ ?

Comment: The prime ideals of $R/I$ correspond to the prime ideals of $R$ that contain $I$, which is $V(I)$. This is Lemma 10.17.7 in the Stacks Project.